# Unable to play sound through Phonegap Android Build

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am having an app build with Cordova and Angular JS. I am trying to play a sound when a new event occurs and I am trying to achieve this by creating an append of  tag within the new event function and then calling #mySound.play(). When I test it on my desktop browser there it is working perfectly on every new event I can hear the sound playing but on the other hand when I create it's APK through Phonegap and test it on my Samsung Galaxy there it isn't playing any sound on new event. Kindly let me know if I am missing anything or what could be a better way to achieve this goal?

```
function displayEvents(data,div_id)
{
    var icon_trans_type=''; var icons=''; var icons2='';
    var htm='';
    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {                          

        var new_tag='';
        if (val.viewed==1){
            $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="locales/android/raw/notify.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>').appendTo('body');
            $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
            new_tag='<div class="new-tag rounded" id="new-event">'+ getTrans('new','new') +'</div>';
        }

    }); 

    //createElement('new-events',htm);
    createElement(div_id,htm);
}
```

Comment: Did that answer helped? Did you cracked it?

Answer (score 0):

The play method provided by HTML5 API is useful for playing media files available on the web. Cordova provides the media plugin to play local media files in device.

[Cordova Media Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media) should do the trick for you as it is supported in various mobile platforms like Android, iOS, Windows, BlackBerry etc.